# Format of the output

Tags: java, eclipse, format

I am using eclipse to run my program. My programs gives 1000 lines as output, and I write the output on a text file successfully. The problem is that the output on the text file is not same as on the console. On the console there are separate lines, but on text file all lines are appended as one line.

How to get the same console format in a text file?

Comment: Can we see the code for the output?

Comment: You are probably doing System.out.println() for console output which writes on new lines. Make sure you have \n every time you want a new line when outputting to text file

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make sure of the following:

1. When writing a line to a file you are including a line separator character(s), you can get a platform independent line separator using the following

   ```
    System.getProperty("line.separator");
   ```
2. When viewing the text file, some app's (like notepad) may not display new line characters the same as others
3. The app you are using to view the file will need to be set to view in a monospaced font (such as Courier New)

Answer (score 0):

completely guessing what you are doing but i think you need to do this.

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, false));
while ( rs.next() ) {
      // code to write a line.
      bw.write("\r\n");
}
```

use

```
 bw.write("\r\n");
```

instead of

```
 bw.newLine();
```

This is for windows systems POSIX systems do newlines differently i believe.

\n is a new line operator just remember that.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using a PrintWriter I would simply do

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
while(...you still have data){
    pw.println(<yourString>);
}
```

you can also append the string `"\n"` to create a new line manually